# Scala unit type, Fibonacci recusive depth function

Tags: scala, recursion, fibonacci

So I want to write a Fibonacci function in scala that outputs a tree like so:

```
fib(3)
| fib(2)
| | fib(1)
| | = 1
| | fib(0)
| | = 0
| = 1
| fib(1)
| = 1
= 2
```

and my current code is as follows:

```
 var depth: Int = 0
  def depthFibonacci(n:Int, depth: Int): Int={
    def fibonnaciTailRec(t: Int,i: Int, j: Int): Int = {
      println(("| " * depth) + "fib(" + t + ")")
      if (t==0) {
        println(("| " * depth) + "=" + j)
        return j
      }
      else if (t==1) {
        println (("| " * depth) + "=" + i)
        return i
      }
      else {
        depthFibonacci(t-1,depth+1) + depthFibonacci(t-2,depth+1)
      }
    }
    fibonnaciTailRec(n,1,0)
  }
  println(depthFibonacci(3,depth))
```

which, when run, looks like:

```
fib(3)
| fib(2)
| | fib(1)
| | =1
| | fib(0)
| | =0
| fib(1)
| =1
2
```

As you can see there is no "= " at the end of any fibonacci numbers greater than 1, and I am unable to implement this in my depthFibonacci function or else the type becomes Unit. How can I fix this?

Comment: Fist of all please, please, please,  [don't use return](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html). Also try to avoid using `var`, it's not recommended and you certainly don't need it here. Now as for your problem, there are two. The final digit comes from the line `println(depthFibonacci(3,depth))` and you aren't adding a `=` in that print statement. The second problem is any number that isn't the final answer and is > 1 **won't be printed at all**.  You need to fix this by adding a print statement in your `else` branch.

Comment: Sorry, imperative programming habits. Also, I can only add the print statement before the recursive call in the else statement, since if I try to add if afterwards, or within the same line, it changes the type of Fibonacci Tail Rec. Adding the print statement before the recursive call in the else branch gives the equals sign before the rest of the inner recursion runs.

Comment: It would be better to return a Tree data structure that represents what you want to print. And then call another function that prints that.

Comment: I agree with what Luis said. If you want to keep it as is, you can always bind the calls to a value, print those and then add the values together. i.e. `val fibMinusOne = ... println(...fibMinusOne...) fibMinusOne + fibMinusTwo`

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for the suggestions! I haven't looked at implementing trees in scala yet but I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Another option would be to use a mutable **String Builder** to construct everything an then print it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this close to what you're after?

```
def depthFib(n:Int, prefix:String = ""):Int = {
  println(s"${prefix}fib($n)")
  val res = n match {
    case x if x < 1 => 0
    case 1 => 1
    case _ => depthFib(n-1, prefix+"| ") +
              depthFib(n-2, prefix+"| ")
  }
  println(s"$prefix= $res")
  res
}
```

usage:

```
depthFib(3)
```

---

## Stack Safe

As it turns out, we can achieve tail call elimination, even without proper tail call recursion, by using `TailCalls` from the standard library.

We start with the Fibonacci implementation as found on the [ScalaDocs page](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/util/control/TailCalls$.html) and add 3 strategically placed `println()` statements.

```
import scala.util.control.TailCalls._

def fib(n: Int, deep:Int=0): TailRec[Int] = {
  println(s"${"| "*deep}fib($n)")
  if (n < 2) {
    println(s"${"| "*deep}= $n")
    done(n)
  } else for {
    x <- tailcall(fib(n-1, deep+1))
    y <- tailcall(fib(n-2, deep+1))
  } yield {
    println(s"${"| "*deep}= ${x+y}")
    x + y
  }
}
```

usage:

```
fib(3).result
```

But things aren't quite what they seem.

```
val f3 = fib(3)  // fib(3)
println("Wha?")  // Wha?
f3.result        // | fib(2)
                 // | | fib(1)
                 // | | = 1
                 // | | fib(0)
                 // | | = 0
                 // | = 1
                 // | fib(1)
                 // | = 1
                 // = 2
```

Thus are the dangers of relying on side effects for your results.

Comment: Well...  Any way to implement a stack safe solution for this one ? I have been trying... but does not seem simple.

Comment: @sarveshseri is not possible if you want to print, side effects make this kind of things impossible. But if you build a tree and then print the tree both operations can be tail-recursive.

Comment: Yes, but then making that tree-building tail-recursive is similarly challenging. Yes, you can use a memoised tree-repository for that, but that adds to the redundancy. Looks like one of the cases where mutability is your friend.

Comment: @sarveshseri yeah that may also be a good solution.

Comment: @jwvh yes that works thank you! I do not need a stack safe solution for this problem so it'll do, although I'm very new to scala so I still have to learn what part of your solution does ahaha.

Comment: @jwvh Thanks for the `TailCalls` reminder, it's a rarely used gem.